# Working with Tasks Xamarin, tasks doesn't run as expected

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, async-await, zxing

I'm working in a project that I use a ZXing Library to read barcodes, but after that I read the barcode I need to do some activities with the information of the barcode.

I'm trying do that with Tasks because I need to acess a webservice too, so the methods need to be async, when I read the barcode the DisplayAlert it's invocated but the next tasks doesn't run and I don't know what I do.

```
private async void buttonEventTank6114(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           await DosingRoutine("TQ6114");  
}



private async Task DosingRoutine(string tankName)
{
    var taskNameTank = await Task.Run(() => Scannen(ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128));
    await this.DisplayAlert("Testing", taskNameTank, "Cancel");

    var taskTankInformation = await OPCUA.GetTankByNameAsync(taskNameTank);


    var taskGetListPackages = await OPCUA.GetPackagesInformationAsync(taskTankInformation.IdBatch, taskTankInformation.MixType);
    await this.DisplayAlert("Testing", taskGetListPackages[0].OperatorName, "Cancel");
}
```

I don't know if I understood right the away of work with tasks, can someone help me?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Task.Run` to call an async method.  The method is *already* asynchronous. (At least according to the name.  If it *isn't* asynchronous, it shouldn't indicate as much in its name.)

Comment: If I use await, the tasks continue without running. And yes the methods are Async

Comment: If I put a value that I know that my webservice will return an object, example:
var taskGetListPackages = await OPCUA.GetPackagesInformationAsync(3006, 1);
    await this.DisplayAlert("Testing", taskGetListPackages[0].OperatorName, "Cancel");

The Display Alert doesn't show, I think because the task doesn't run.

Comment: `Task.Run` just performs the same operation in a thread pool thread.  If that code isn't working for you, then you should figure out what the *actual* problem is.  If that operation doesn't run when run from the current thread then something is *seriously* wrong and you need to address it.